# How can you use threading to send multiple web requests at a time in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, asynchronous, web

I have a simple ASP.NET applet, and I'm trying to learn basic multithreading to make it run more smoothly.

Let's say I have a button hooked up to the following method:

```
private NlSearch search;

protected void SearchButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int resultCount = search.MakeRequests(SearchForm.Text);
        resultsLabel.Text += SearchForm.Text + ": " + resultCount.ToString() + "     occurances";
    }
```

All MakeRequests does is issue a POST request to do a search on a 3rd party website and grabs the number of results from the response. The search term along with the number of results is then added to the page.

However if I were to do something like submit a new search before the first search has responded, it will simply interrupt the original search and only the most recent search will write it's results to the label.

I understand there's a way to do this with C# threading, but I can't figure out how to use tasks correctly to do this. I tried putting the body of the method into a second method with no arguments that I then used to create and run a task, but this did not change the behavior so I think I was using tasks incorrectly.

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: What I've tried so far: both answers seemed to 'work' at retrieving values but for some reason neither actually added them to the label for some reason. For example

```
protected void NewSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() => MakeRequest(SearchForm.Text)).Start();
    }
```

and

```
protected void MakeRequest(string text)
    {
            int resultCount = search.MakeRequests(text);
            if (resultsLabel != null) resultsLabel.Text += text + ": " + resultCount + "     occurances";
    }
```

seemed to retrieve the value but the label does not change.

Comment: Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(YourMethod));?
Edit: You could also use the ThreadPool class. For more info, check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Show us what you tried. Based on that, I could probably tell you in what direction to look.
You might want to first check out Threads and Threadpools before delving into Tasks.

Comment: Why not disabling "Search" button until first response is received or timed out?

Comment: @KappaG3 I wouldn't try doing that stuff on my own you can quickly run the thread pool dry. .NET allows for managed parallelism with Tasks.

I would use this kind of stuff:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

Comment: see my most recent answer, you want to use threads with Dispatcher, so that the UI isn't blocked when the tasks are running and so that the label gets updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a WPF app, you should use both threads and Dispatcher, because only the UI thread can write to a label. More specifically, you should use the dispatcher as a callback to update anything in the UI when a task is complete:

```
protected void SearchButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(() => MakeRequest(SearchForm.Text)).Start();
}

protected void MakeRequest(string text)
{
    int resultCount = search.MakeRequests(text);

    // tell UI thread to update label
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                resultsLabel.Text += text + ": " + resultCount + "     occurances";
            }));
}
```

**Edit1:** use Dispatcher not just threads

**Edit2:** use both Dispatcher and threads

Comment: I've tried this one and the first answer and for some reason the control flow isn't even reaching MakeRequest.

Comment: What do you mean by control flow? This starts a new thread, so if you're using a debugger to step through the thread that hits SearchButtonClick, it won't reach MakeRequest. Are you using visual studio?

Comment: Yeah. In visual studio. I'm inexperienced with threading so sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology. I was actually mistaken and what seems to be happening based on the debugger is that it's correctly retrieving resultsCount but isn't writing it to the Label for some reaosn.

Comment: Thanks. It's generating a cannot-reference-non-static-method in static context error, am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: What is generating that error? You shouldn't need anything static, and shouldn't see that error

Comment: "Error1: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, params object[])'". Dispatcher is static but it says that BeginInvoke is not a static method.

Comment: try doing `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Comment: `this` does not seem to have a member dispatcher from inheriting System.Web.Ui.Page. Should I be inhering something with a Dispatcher method? Alternately, a less braindead way for me to design it would be to just store the retrieved data in a collection and just update the label with the contents of the collection. Is there a way I could do this every time a thread completes without running into the thread access problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would use .NET Task as they manage the thread pool for you.

LINK: [Task [Managed parallelism]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

```
protected void SearchButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var text = SearchForm.Text;
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
   {
      var resultCount = search.MakeRequests(text);
      resultsLabel.Text += text + ": " + resultCount + "     occurances";
   });
}
```

Comment: you'll want to grab SearchForm.Text before starting the task, as it could change before the task runs

Comment: I don't think locking on a local variable makes sense!

Comment: This won't work in a WPF app, only the UI thread can update the UI.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about that magic thread. Thanks for the clarification.