# How do I display query results in the same order they were made in a multithreaded web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842937/how-can-you-use-threading-to-send-multiple-web-requests-at-a-time-in-c) for some help on using multithreading in a simple ASP.NET Windows forms applet to make searches run faster, and got some good answers. However as a result of using threading on this app (and not having much experience with it), I've run into a number of new design problems.

I've written a simple applet that sends a POST request to a third party website to use its search bar, and then return an integer extracted from a string on the page that indicates how many results were found for a given search term.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private NlSearch search;
    private static List<SearchResult> resultsList = new List<SearchResult>(); 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        search = new NlSearch();
    }

    protected void AddSearchMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = SearchForm.Text;
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MakeRequest(text));
        task.Wait();

        resultsLabel.Text = "";
        foreach (var v in resultsList)
        {
            resultsLabel.Text += v.SearchTerm + ": " + v.Count + " occurances<br/>";
        }
    }

    protected void ClearSearchMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultsLabel.Text = "";
        resultsList.Clear();
    }

    protected void MakeRequest(string text)
    {
        SearchResult s = new SearchResult
        {
            SearchTerm = text,
            Count = 0
        };
        resultsList.Add(s);
        s.Count = search.MakeRequests(text);
    }
}
```

AddSearchMethod and ClearSearchMethod correspond with an "Add Search" and "Clear Search" button, and interact with a SearchForm textfield and a resultsLabel label.

The desired behavior is:

1. that the client can enter a single search term in the SearchForm field, submit, and the application will run the search, add the result to the resultsList List, and then write the contents of the list to resultsLabel, which works as intended.
2. I would like for the client to be able to submit as many search terms as they would like into SearchForm, and then write those to the list in the order they were made. The response to the HTTP request is quite slow and this greatly improves the usability.

I run into a lot of issues with #2. You can submit as many search terms as you want before you receive a response, but the response is extremely slow and seems to scale with the number of requests, suggesting that they are not running concurrently. This also fails to preserve the order, so that if I enter search terms in order "1990" "1991" 1992" "1993", they will display in the order that the response is received, rather than the order they are made.

Not knowing much about threading with web apps, I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot these issues.

Edit: There also seems to be some loss of requests. For example if I enter in order "boston1" through "boston10" the output is

```
boston1: 302 occurances
boston3: 265 occurances
boston2: 227 occurances
boston: 10220056 occurances
boston7: 389 occurances
boston10: 109 occurances
```

Comment: You're creating a task, which launches another thread, but then you immediately turn around and have the main thread wait for the task to complete.  You have no concurrency.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Do you have a sense of an alternative? I added the wait because without it, the main thread would hit the foreach loop to write the results too soon and it wouldn't print properly. If I put the writing routine in a thread it wouldn't be able to write because it wouldn't have access to the UI thread, and I wasn't able to get Dispatchers to work properly with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a sorted list and keep track of your requests using a static request ID number.

```
private static SortedList<long, SearchResult> resultsList = new SortedList<long, SearchResult>();
...
    foreach (var v in resultsList.Values)
    {
...
public static long RequestID = 0;
protected void MakeRequest(string text)
{
    SearchResult s = new SearchResult
    {
        SearchTerm = text,
        Count = 0
    };
    resultsList.Add(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref RequestID), s);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to remedy the ordering issue for some reason.

Comment: @ProtonBetaDecay - The code for NlSearch.MakeRequests(string) will likely be needed for a more complete solution.